# My Ajax POST is coming up as an error even though I am returning 200

Tags: ajax, jersey

I am making an AJAX post to a Jersey Resource. I build an image and return it. The issue is, no matter what status I return, Ajax thinks it is an error. I can actually use the error message (via error.responseTest) and it works fine. But it is ugly. What do I return to make it a success? I have returned OK(200), Accepted(202) and Created(201). All of them give me an error message but in my Console Network tab, I get a success (green with the proper status).

I am returning it like this:

```
    return Response.status(Response.Status.ACCEPTED).entity(image).header('Content-Type',"image/png").build();
```

My JS code:

```
$.ajax( Monocle.config.Sightline.jobUrl + "/sightline", {
        type: "POST",
        processData: false,
        data: JSON.stringify({
            Lat1: Monocle.Sightline.BBOX(feature,2),
            Long1: Monocle.Sightline.BBOX(feature,1),
            Lat2: Monocle.Sightline.BBOX(feature,4),
            Long2: Monocle.Sightline.BBOX(feature,3),
            OrgLat:observerCoords[0].lat,
            OrgLong:observerCoords[0].lon,
            ObHeight: feature.attributes.observerHeight,
            TargHeight: feature.attributes.targetHeight,
            OuterRadius: feature.attributes.outerRadius,
            LVA: feature.attributes.lowerVertAngle,
            UVA: feature.attributes.upperVertAngle,
            sAzimuth: feature.attributes.startAzimuth,
            eAzimuth: feature.attributes.endAzimuth,
            outputType: "MAX"
        }),
        contentType: "application/json",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function( results ){
            var graphic = new OpenLayers.Layer.Image(
                Monocle.currentWidget.name + " Destination " + featurenum,
                "data:image/png;base64," + results,
                new OpenLayers.Bounds(Monocle.Sightline.BBOX(feature,1), Monocle.Sightline.BBOX(feature,2), Monocle.Sightline.BBOX(feature,3),Monocle.Sightline.BBOX(feature,4)),
                new OpenLayers.Size(580, 288),
                { isBaseLayer: false,
                    opacity: 0.3,
                    displayOutsideMaxExtent: true
                });
            feature.legionObject = graphic;
            graphic.relatedlayer = Monocle.currentWidget.name + " Destination " + featurenum;

            Monocle.Map.map.addLayer(graphic);
        },
        error: function(errMsg) {
            // TODO: really handle any errors

        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting `dataType: "json",` means that your response is to be `json` which it isn't that would cause the error so just remove it.
Also is your image data has to be base64 encoded to make a data uri.

Comment: Yeah it is in Base64. I can display the image if I move the success stuff to error and make the results errMsg.responseText. But I think your suggestion will work.

Comment: Yep. I removed dataType: "json" and it worked like a charm. Thanks!